# How to read response from Github login identity provider in ASP.net MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, github, identity

I'm doing a web application and login system based on Github identity provider.I run the application and click "Login with Github". Once GitHub authorizes user, it returns to Callback action method in my controller. The problem is how could i read the response from Github (return url with code and state) and how to get the access_token further ?